# Dynamic Field Handling Using Selenium RC + Java

Tags: java, selenium

How to handle dynamic field in Selenium RC?
I am using completely Java Code.

Comment: This sentence should be in Google Search text box.

Comment: Probably worth explaining what you mean by "Dynamic Field"

Answer (score 1):

On general question, general answer - try searching by [XPath](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example1.html) - In most cases the dynamic fields are on the same place in the DOM. So while ID can change, the relative path does not.

Answer (score 0):

See this once . it may help you.

You need to program it. So it is not possible using Selenium IDE, but you can use Selenium Webdriver. see the java code for this question.

[selenium with dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027786/using-selenium-with-dynamic-values).